# Can I find the region of the found categories in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

We have been using Tensorflow for image classification, and we all see the results for the Admiral Grace Hopper, and we get:

```
military uniform (866): 0.647296
suit (794): 0.0477196
academic gown (896): 0.0232411
bow tie (817): 0.0157356
bolo tie (940): 0.0145024
```

I was wondering if there is any way to get the coordinates for each category within the image.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow doesn't have sample code yet on image **detection** and **localization** but it's an open research problem with different approaches to do it using deep nets; for example you can lookup the papers on algorithms called OverFeat and YOLO (You Only Look Once).

Also, usually there's some preprocessing on the object coordinates labels, or postprocessing to suppress duplicate detections. Usually a second, different network is used to classify the object once it's detected.